# how to check if user is online with c++ desktop application

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, visual-c++

I have application that needs to load local html file if user is offline, if not it will load his web application via embedded control.

How to check if user is online with c++ desktop application that has embedded ie browser control?

Comment: how do you define "being online"?

Comment: What do you want to use this information for? Isn't it just easier to try and retrieve some data or ping a known good host, like google?

Comment: if user is connected to the internet, and can open web pages, online

Comment: I have application that needs to load local html file if user is offline, if not it will load his web application via embedded control

Comment: why don't you just use HTML5 "object" element. it does that checking of availability, and fallback, for you. Keep It Simple, Stupid.

Comment: @Marko: Connected to the internet != can open web pages. "f user is offline" - attempt to launch webapp. In case of failure, load offline page.

Comment: @Alf but ie6-8 users don't have html5

Comment: @Marko: it think a far more fruitful response would be to check if you could make the solution work in spite of the perceived possible problem (PPP). perhaps even those old Microsoft browsers support "object", with of course IE idiosyncracies if so, but still? and perhaps, if they don't, you can put some application requirements? and perhaps, if also that positive approach fails, you could still keep things simple by just attempting wget on the resource? so on. think positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [InternetGetConnectedState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. However, make sure you honor the comments given in the Remarks section, especially:

> A return value of TRUE from InternetGetConnectedState indicates that
>   at least one connection to the Internet is available

You may also try to directly use the [InternetCheckConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for your particular URL.

There are also newer COM interfaces that have the same (or better) functionality:

- [INetworkListManager::GetConnectivity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370773.aspx)
- [INetworkListManager::get_IsConnectedToInternet()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Network Location Awareness (NLA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine the characteristics of the current network(s) to which the machine is attached.  This is not quite the same as checking whether 'the user is online' but should be sufficient.

Even then, you cannot guarantee that the app will load properly if the internet is accessible.  If the online case is normal, you might be better off just trying the online load and falling back to local HTML if that fails.

Comment: Yes, but how to fall back? I've tried reading html title, but when user is offline browser control doesn't read title but domain instead, and it complicates checking

Comment: How about @Alf's suggestion in the comments?

Comment: but ie6-8 users don't have html5

Answer (score 0):

You can try to ping www.google.com. If using Visual C++, you can use [IcmpSendEcho function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366050%28VS.85%29.aspx).